# app.send is not a function error in WebStorm while writing Node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I am a beginner in Node.js and I am still following tutorials. I did exactly the same thing the tutorial suggested me but I still got this error. This is the error I keep getting every next line and in every next code.

The code written in WebStorm and I just modified two lines in this:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const path = require('path');
 const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 const logger = require('morgan');
 const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   app.send('This is a Node Program.');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  let err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The error:

```
app.send is not a function

TypeError: app.send is not a function
    at C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\app.js:23:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\NodeDemo\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
```

Can someone help me with this error? I might be missing some library files or something. Can some help me to fix this error and suggest me what should be done in order to prevent these errors?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to send with "res" object like this:

```
res.send('This is a Node Program.');
```

Hope it helps.